# Автоматическая инъекция стилей при их подключении в webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

Я указываю стили как модули, что бы явно описать зависимость js файла от стилей.

Я хочу, что бы при подключении стилей (`require('file.css')`), они автоматически внедрялись на страницу.

Загрузчик `style-loader` делает это. Но я хочу использовать плагин `mini-css-extract-plugin`, который не работает в связке с `style-loader` и в документации которого сказано:

> This plugin should be used only on production builds without
>   style-loader in the loaders chain, especially if you want to have HMR
>   in development.

Пример проблемы: если у меня есть несколько js файлов "точек входа" и в рантайме мне понадобится подключить один из конечных бандлов, например `optional-module.js`, придётся вручную подключать и его зависимости, как например `optional-module.css`. Я хочу, что бы модуль сам занимался этим.

p.s. `html-webpack-plugin`, разумеется, не решает мою проблему, потому что предназначен для генерации статических страниц, а мой вопрос о подключении стилей в рантайме.